# How to fetch the particular string from text file in Installshield

Tags: installshield

What I am trying to do is I want to read the "Revision(REV_057)" from text file.
Text file contains many Hardware Id's like

```
 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B56&SUBSYS_304A103C&REV_057
 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B56&SUBSYS_304A103C
 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B56&CC_040300 

 szDevID1 = "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B56&SUBSYS_304A103C&";
 OpenFileMode(FILE_MODE_NORMAL); 
 OpenFile(FileHandle,TempDir, "sample.txt"); 
 while(GetLine(FileHandle, ReturnLine) = 0) 

     if( ReturnLine % szDevID1 ) then
            lsTokens = ListCreate (STRINGLIST); 
            StrGetTokens (lsToken, svReturnLine, "&");
            ListSetIndex (lsToken, LISTLAST);
            ListCurrentString (lsTokens, szsample); 
              MessageBox(":FINAL: szsample " + szsample, INFORMATION);
              /*  ISSUE: Iam expecting szsample as REV_057 */
           endif;
        endwhile;
```

what is the issue in above code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run it, but looks like the problem is over here: The script is iterating through `ReturnLine`, but the string variable which you are splitting called `svReturnLine`. Correct it and try again. Let me know.

Also, make sure you are destroying lists after use with `ListDestroy` and closing the file with `CloseFile`